# File I/O - How HDD or SSD works with OS file system?

Tags: file-systems, io

I've studied how data transfer with secondary storage(HDD or SSD) works.

Would you mind to check that my understanding is correct?

File system

- block is basic read/write *logical* unit which is used in file system
- OS page for memory management is different from block
- OS page size might be equal to block size or not, but making two units have same size might be better for performance

In HDD,

- A sector(= disk block) is minimal *hardware* unit for read/write in HDD
- block is composed of single or multiple sectors
- block size is multiplier of single sector size
- When storing a file less than block size, still a single block (i.e. multiple sectors) is allocated to store the file and remaining space of the block is wasted.
- When a program reads the file, (not only just the file but) the entire block containing the file should be *transferred* to main memory.
- When the entire block is loaded to memory buffer, from now on, the loaded block is recognized as OS page.
- Then, the actual file is extracted from OS page.

In SSD,

- SSD is much faster than HDD because it has no mechanical part like arm
- In SSD, basic *hardware* unit for read/write is SSD page
- In SSD, erase is based on SSD block (SSD block is independent term from block)
- With SSD, block is (normally) composed of single or multiple SSD pages
- block size is (normally) multiplier of single SSD page size, but it is also possible that block size is less than single SSD page size (though it might cause bad effect)
- When a program reads the file less than block size, the entire block containing the file should be *transferred* to main memory
- remaining part is same with HDD

Is my understanding correct?

Thank you in advance for your time, checking and comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, your understanding is correct.

Thank goodness we see no mention of cylinder-head-sector, R.I.P.!
There is one item I'd like to emphasize.

> SSD is much faster than HDD because it has no mechanical part like arm

True. There are two I/O patterns: random & sequential. Let's look at random reads.
In HDD we have to wait on mechanical delays for head motion to a new track,
then settle time, and rotational latency for sector to appear below the head.
In SSD we have none of that. So random reads go as fast as sequential, right?
No! There are still setup latencies when seeking to a new location.
They are smaller than for Winchester technology, but the same old
lessons about "prefer bulk reads!" continue to hold.
All up and down the memory hierarchy, from L1 cache out to secondary storage,
if you can organize data for sequential access, you will see lower elapsed times.

Answer (score 1):

In principle, a HDD can read or write complete blocks. An SSD can read a block or write to a complete erased block, and it can erase sets of usually 32 or 64 consecutive blocks.

The difference in behaviour is usually not handled by the OS but by firmware in the SSD drive. The SSD drive keeps track of where blocks are allocated on the SSD drive - blocks are not stored where the OS thinks they are. It keeps track of where erased blocks are, and which data is unused.

When the OS asks to read say block 119, the firmware will check where that block is stored and read it. When the OS asks to write block 119, and that block isn’t stored anywhere, then the firmware will find the location of an erased block, remember the location, and write the block.

Now if the OS asks to write block 119 and that block is stored somewhere: The block cannot be written to its old location. Instead the firmware remembers that the old location is unused and writes to a new location.

Eventually we run out of erased blocks. In that case we find 32 or 64 consecutive blocks with no or few blocks used. The firmware reads the used blocks, erases consecutive blocks, then writes the used blocks back.

SSD drives have another call apart from read and write: If the OS deletes or truncates a file, it tells the SSD drive that these blocks are unused. So when blocks are erased, these unused blocks don’t need copying.

And there is one more call for security: The contents of an overwritten block usually stays on the SSD for a while. If the OS wants to 100% remove it, it uses a different write call which is guaranteed to erase the old contents of the block.

PS Nothing says you can’t store many small files in one block. Some applications can produce hundreds of tiny files. Say 1000 files of 100 bytes each. If a block = 4k then using 25 blocks instead of 1000 is a significant saving. That would be done by the OS.

PS You don’t want to write everything to the disk immediately on an SSD drive, because writing to the same block multiple times is expensive. On the other hand, having cached writes is dangerous in case of a power cut. SSD drives usually have an internal power source (capacitor) that has enough power to guarantee all cached writes can be performed if the normal power source goes away.

Comment: Do you have some source for the Secure erase call? I was only aware of a call to clear the entire drive, not anything for individual blocks.

Comment: @gnasher729 Thank you for your comments :) May I get confirmation about first PS? So you means that multiple tiny files can be stored in same block, right? That what is words or terms about it? I want to search to find and study some references. Do you mean `block suballocation`?

Comment: That’s done on iOS especially for erasing encryption keys. It’s obviously easy (even though a bit inefficient) for the firmware but quite difficult for the OS.

Answer (score 0):

> block is basic read/write logical unit which is used in file system

Yes.

> OS page for memory management is different from block
> OS page size might be equal to block size or not, but making two units have same size might be better for performance

Specifically the caching system in the Linux kernel works in terms of pages, it's much simpler to manage this if filesystem blocks are a multiple of pages. I can't speak for the structure of other operating systems.

> A sector(= disk block) is minimal hardware unit for read/write in HDD

Mostly yes.

A wrinkle with modern drives is that the "logical sectors" used for communication over the drive's interface may be different from the physical sectors used to store the data on the disk. It's very common for drives to have 4kB physical sectors but to still use 512 byte logical sectors. On such drives there will be a significant performance penalty on operations whose size or alignment doesn't match the physical sectors.

> block is composed of single or multiple sectors
> block size is multiplier of single sector size
> When storing a file less than block size, still a single block (i.e. multiple sectors) is allocated to store the file and remaining space of the block is wasted.

Yes.

> SSD is much faster than HDD because it has no mechanical part like arm

Specificaly no matter how densely the information is packed on the platter, and how small the operations are, the number of independent operations is limited by seek time and rotational latency. For each read the heads must be moved into place and then the drive must rotate to the right rotational position. On average this means waiting half a revoloution.

Being mechanical properties, both seek time and rotational latency are difficult to reduce further.

> In SSD, basic hardware unit for read/write is SSD page
> In SSD, erase is based on SSD block (SSD block is independent term from block)
> With SSD, block is (normally) composed of single or multiple SSD pages
> block size is (normally) multiplier of single SSD page size, but it is also possible that block size is less than single SSD page size (though it might cause bad effect)

The thing you are missing about SSDs is that they were/are designed to be a drop-in replacement for hard drives.

The result of this is that there is a translation layer between the raw flash memory and the interface. At the raw flash level flash can only be erased in large blocks, but the controller on the SSD hides that from the host computer. As far as the host computer is concerned it can write where it likes, when it likes. It is up to the translation layer to remap the writes from the host controller to spread the wear across the flash array and to deal with "garbage" pages by copying pages that are still in use from one eraseblock to another and then erasing the source eraseblock.